# Problems upgrading graphics card driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card

I recently re-installed Windows 7 Ultimate on my machine, before doing a complete Windows Update which automatically installed many drivers for the hardware components on board.

Then I began some OpenGL software development projects, and I noticed that every time I run the OpenGL program, everything else on Windows runs very very slowly. Windows Explorer, for example, needs 5 seconds to create a new window. As soon as I exit the OpenGL program, everything runs fine again. During the OpenGL session, the CPU and RAM resources are not exhausted (CPU at about 20%).

So I suspected that I got an old or wrong graphics card driver. The reseller where I bought the machine just tells me that the graphics card I got installed is an **`ATI Radeon HD 4800 Series`**, this is also the device that's listed in the Device Manager, and Device Manager tells me that the driver is up to date.

I then downloaded and installed **Catalyst Control Center** from ATI, which apparently did some driver updates. I also went through the settings of CCC, switching everything that was there to 'Optimal Performance'. No noticeable effects. CCC tells me that I have an `ATI Radeon HD 4800 Series` chipset with device ID `9442` and GPU memory size `4351 MB`.

Today I noticed that the new Google Maps is telling me *"You are currently running in Lite mode and 3D Earth view is not available."* According to their help and various sources on the internet, this should not happen on the latest Chrome/Win7.

**How can I find out whether I have the latest driver for my graphics card? How can I at least find out the exact model of the card?**

Here's my configuration:

- 8 GB RAM ('normal CPU RAM')
- Win7 x64 Ultimate
- Chrome 28.0.1500.72
- Catalyst Control Center 2012.1116.1515.27190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh. The culprit was `LogMeIn Mirror Driver`:

[image]

As soon as that one was disabled and the PC was restarted, everything runs like a charm.

Comment: BTW, you might want to mark this as answered. Rather interesting find, though!